# Anime about a girl whose necklace can summon musical fairies

Tags: story-identification, anime, fairy

I’m looking for an anime whose name I forgot, it had something to do with the main character's necklace and it somehow brought like music fairies to help her. It’s been a long time so I can’t remember everything but I know she had just moved into a dorm.

Comment: At the moment your question does not provide enough clues to identify the anime you saw; if you could have a look at this [checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/40711) maybe you could recollect some more details to [edit] in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for [*Mirmo Zibang*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1744/Wagamama%E2%98%86Fairy_Mirumo_de_Pon)

It doesn't show a necklace though but they are definitely music fairies and necklaces with powers might appear every so often. But the fairies come from the cups.